# When to reload UITableView after retrieving from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase storage to store users' profile pictures and I'm trying to display these profile pictures in a UITableView.

The problem is I can't find a good point in the code to reload the table view's data once the images have finished being retrieved. Any time I call tableView.reloadData(), it seems to be before the images have finished downloading as the table cell's image view is left blank.

Currently, I'm iterating through the users that will show on the table view and getting their profile pictures with a call to this function:

```
func loadProfilePicture(userId: String, index: Int) {
        // Load the stored image
        usersRef.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // Load user's profile picture from Firebase Storage if it exists (exists if the user has a profPic URL in the database)
            if snapshot.hasChild("profilePictureUrl") {
                self.usersStorageRef.child(userId + "/ProfilePicture").data(withMaxSize: 20*1024*1024, completion: {(data, error) in
                    let storagePicture = UIImage(data:data!)
                    // Sets the user's profile picture to the loaded image
                    self.nearbyUsers[index].profilePicture = storagePicture
                })
            } else {
                print("Error -- Loading Profile Picture")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }
```

Where `nearbyUsers` is my table view's data source and my tableview's cellForRowAt function looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
        let user = nearbyUsers[indexPath.row]

        cell.labelUserName.text = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName

        print("refreshing")
        if user.profilePicture != nil {
            cell.imageViewProfilePicture.image = user.profilePicture
        }


        return cell
    }
```

I've tried a few variations of the code I'm currently at such as:

-reloading the table view data after the loop that calls the loadProfilePicture function on each user

-reloading the table view's data without dispatching to the main thread

but to no avail

So how can I reload my table view's data while ensuring that all of the profile pictures have been loaded?

Thanks!